# Class not found after reloading php

Tags: php, jquery

I'm sure this has been asked before, but I was unable to find a relevant question, maybe I'm using the wrong search terms...

In my index.php, I'm including class_lib.php, which contains my Database class. Then I'm including a php file that displays some information gathered from the database, and it runs fine on initial load. Finally, I have a button that refreshes the included php file, using jQuery to .load() it again, replacing the initial html/script.

On the second load, I'm getting:

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Database' not found in path/to/module.php Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in path/to/module.php on line 33

Obviously, line 33 is the first time I call the Database class in module.php

```
 $database = new Database();
```

Stupidly, I tried including class_lib.php again in module.php, which resulted in:

Fatal error: Cannot declare class lead, because the name is already in use in path/to/Class_lib.php

I read something about autoloaders, I've read some stuff about require_once, include_once, etc - alas, I am still at a loss. Here is my (simplified) code...

inside index.php

```
<html><head>
<?php include('class_lib.php') ?>
</head><body>
<div id="module">
    <?php include('module.php') ?> //Include the module, displays fine on first run
</div>
</body></html>
```

class_lib.php

```
class Database{
    //private vars
    //public functions, __construct(), query(), bind(), execute(), others
}
```

module.php

```
$database = new Database();
//run queries, display results, the usual
<div id="refreshButton">Refresh This Module</div>

<script>
$('#refreshButton').on('click', function(){
    $('#module').load('module.php');
}
</script>
```

So if I can't include the Database class twice, and the class isn't found on the second load, how can I make this work?

Comment: Firstly WHY do you have to load again? Secondly. can't you tell the PHP when you load from Ajax not to execute the database call?

Comment: The module displays a list of uploaded files, and has a "drawer" of sorts to drag-drop new files. The refresh button is clicked when you want to exit the drawer and go back to the list. If new files have been uploaded, the list needs to be refreshed without the page refreshing, hence the reason for using .load().

Comment: and the second database call is necessary, otherwise it won't get the updated list.

Comment: so it's when you click and load the module.php as an ajax call that you have the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

either place `include('class_lib.php')` inside the module.php file or
call use `include_once('class_lib.php')` in both places, then if it is already included it wont call it again.

Comment: Literally got it working seconds before seeing this post. I ended up using require_once in the index.php, and require_once again in the module.php file. Also, not included in my "simplified" code was that Class_lib.php was in a different folder hierarchy, so I had to use dirname( __FILE__ ) to get the right path to the required file. Either way, its working now, thanks for your help.